# Getting the negative integer from a two's complement value Embedded C

Tags: c, embedded

I know that many had similar questions over here about converting from/to two's complement format and I tried many of them but nothing seems to help in my case.

Well, I'm working on an embedded project that involves writing/reading registers of a slave device over SPI. The register concerned here is a 22-bit position register that stores the uStep value in two's complement format and it ranges from -2^21 to +2^21 -1. The problem is when I read the register, I get a big integer that has nothing to do with the actual value.

Example:

After sending a command to the slave to move 4000 steps (forward/positive), I read the position register and I get exactly 4000. However, if I send a reverse move command, say -1, and then read the register, the value I get is something like 4292928. I believe it's the negative offset of the register as the two's complement has no zero. I have no problem sending a negative integer to the device to move x number of steps, however, getting the actual negative integer from the value retrieved is something else.

I know that this involves two's complement but the question is, how to get the actual negative integer out of that strange value? I mean, if I moved the device -4000 steps, what I have to do to get the exact value for the negative steps moved so far from my register?

Comment: This also depends on the endianess of the device/protocol versus the endianess of your CPU. Have you considered that part?

Comment: Anyway, please post the actual problematic code, since this will be hard to answer without an example.

Comment: Well, not really, but I believe the answers presume a big endian machine and they just worked fine without any problem.

Answer (score 3):

You need to sign-extend bit 21 through the bits to the left.

For negative values when bit 21 is set, you can do this by ORring the value with `0xFFC00000`.

For positive values when bit 21 is clear, you can ensure by ANDing the value with `0x003FFFFF`.

Comment: This works only for two's-complement machines, admittedly the norm. See my answer for an alternative.

Answer (score 3):

The solutions by Clifford and Weather Vane assume the target machine is two's-complement. This is very likely true, but a solution that removes this dependency is:

```
static const int32_t sign_bit = 0x00200000;

int32_t pos_count = (getPosRegisterValue() ^ sign_bit) - sign_bit;
```

It has the additional advantage of being branch-free.

Comment: Good target agnostic solution that does not sacrifice efficiency.  Though in 27 years of embedded development, I have never encountered a target that was not 2's complement.  There again in 27 years, I have never thought of that solution, so there you go!

Comment: I think this also assumes the target is two's-complement. Isn't that a requirement for the presence of the `int32_t` type?

Comment: int32_t is a signed 32 bit integer, format is not specified. I used it to indicate that the number is bigger than 22 bits, but the code will work with any signed integer type larger than 22 bits.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest method perhaps is simply to shift the position value left by 10 bits and assign to an `int32_t`.  You will then have a 32 bit value and the position will be scaled up by 2<sup>10</sup> (1024), and have 32 bit resolution, but 10 bit granularity, which normally shouldn't matter since the position units are entirely arbitrary in any case, and can be converted to real-world units if necessary taking into account the scaling:

```
int32_t pos_count = (int32_t)(getPosRegisterValue() << 10) ;
```

Where `getPosRegisterValue()` returns a `uint32_t`.

If you do however want to retain 22 bit resolution then it is simply a case of dividing the value by 1024:

```
int32_t pos_count = (int32_t)(getPosRegisterValue() << 10)) / 1024 ;
```

Both solutions rely in the *implementation-defined* behaviour of casting a `uint32_t` of value not representable in an `int32_t`; but one a two's complement machine any plausible implementation will not modify the bit-pattern and the result will be as required.

Another perhaps less elegant solution also retaining 22 bit resolution and single bit granularity is:

```
int32_t pos_count = getPosRegisterValue() ;

// If 22 bit sign bit set...
if( (pos_count & 0x00200000) != 0)
{
    // Sign-extend to 32bit
    pos_count |= 0xFFC00000 ;
}
```

It would be wise perhaps to wrap the solution is a function to isolate any implementation defined behaviour:

```
int32_t posCount()
{
    return (int32_t)(getPosRegisterValue() << 10)) / 1024 ;
}
```

Comment: Shifting into the two's complement sign bit is also undefined behavior (C99 §6.5.7/3-4). See my answer for an alternative.

Comment: Of course it is a two's complement machine, as this has been mentioned explicitly in the device's datasheet. All the answers are great and just tried two of them and they solved my problem. I can't expect anything more!

Comment: Note that I have removed the part about right-shift; all solutions exhibited undefined behaviour as pointed out by @DougCurrie. This can be solved with his solution, or by `getPosRegisterValue()` returning `uint32_t`  - casting the unsigned value with the MSB set is _implementation-defined_ rather then _undefined_ so for any specific compiler/target combination, it will at lest be _defined_ if not portable.  I have changed the answer to reflect this.

Comment: Yep, that's actually what I have used to solve it avoiding other solutions that involve shifting.